# Работа с экраном блокировки

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос: как происходит работа с экраном блокировки, а именно: какая блокировка установлена, сколько попыток ввода пароля уже было. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю в "родном" Android'е на экран блокировки нет пароля. Пример блокировки и разблокировки [экрана здесь](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.ru/2010/03/enabling-and-disabling-lock-screen-in.html)

Обычно производители телефонов сами пишут локи/анлоки экранов в составе своих оболочек, как например HTC Sense и Samsung TouchWiz. Смотрите документацию по ним. У обоих есть свои API (правда, довольно куцые).

Comment: есть там защита паролем. А также паттерн, распознавание лица, пин-код. 

А блокировщик в TouchWiz - это бажная поделка:)

Comment: есть там все...но по каждому производителю делать это гемор

Comment: Ну же ребят, неужели никто не знает?

Comment: @kwon посмотри на этот [тред](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically)